# How to get the latest value from an observable or a subject without subscribtion?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have built a simple Store service. In init method in the store I make an http get request to get the courses.

I want to edit one of the courses based on the courseId and changes. For that I have a save method in the store. In this method I want to get the latest snapshot from the courses just one time. But as I subscribe to get the values, I got "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error. For that reason I don't want to subscribe as my purpose is to get the latest course value from the subject.

course-dialog.component.html

```
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button class="mat-raised-button" (click)="close()">Close</button>

  <button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" #saveButton (click)="save()">
    Save
  </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

course-dialog.component.ts

```
save() {
    this.store.saveCourse(this.course.id, this.form.value).subscribe(
      () => this.close(),
      (err) => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

store.service.ts

```
export class Store {
  private subject = new BehaviorSubject<Course[]>([]);
  courses$ = this.subject.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  init() {
    //const http$ = createHttpObservable("/api/courses");

    this.http
      .get<Course[]>("/api/courses")
      .pipe(
        tap(() => console.log("HTTP request executed")),
        map((res) => res["payload"])
      )
      .subscribe((courses) => this.subject.next(courses));
  }

  selectBeginnerCourses() {
    return this.filterByCategory("BEGINNER");
  }

  selectAdvancedCourses() {
    return this.filterByCategory("ADVANCED");
  }

  filterByCategory(category: string) {
    return this.courses$.pipe(
      map((courses) => courses.filter((course) => course.category === category))
    );
  }

  saveCourse(courseId: number, changes) {
    let courses: Course[];
    let newCourse: Course;
    let courseIndex: number;
    let newCourses: Course[];

    this.subject
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        newCourses = data;
        courseIndex = newCourses.findIndex((course) => course.id === courseId);
        newCourses[courseIndex] = {
          ...newCourses[courseIndex],
          ...changes,
        };
        console.log(newCourses);
        this.subject.next(newCourses);
      })
      .unsubscribe();

    return this.http.put(`api/courses/${courseId}`, {
      body: JSON.stringify(changes),
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The error is from the fact that you call `this.subject.next(newCourses);` in your subscription, creating an infinite loop.

Comment: I’m curious as to why you need the subject subscribe in the first place? Seems like determining conditions and the nexting it should be sufficient? If you need the latest emitted value you get do a getValue() on the BehaviorSubject imperatively..

Answer (score 0):

```ts
this.subject
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        newCourses = data;
        courseIndex = newCourses.findIndex((course) => course.id === courseId);
        newCourses[courseIndex] = {
          ...newCourses[courseIndex],
          ...changes,
        };
        console.log(newCourses);
        this.subject.next(newCourses);
      })
```

above portion causing problem.actually it became a infinite loop.You need to add a condition for `this.subject.next(newCourses);` or create separate `Subject` for **newCources**

snippet with condition

```ts
this.subject
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        newCourses = data;
        courseIndex = newCourses.findIndex((course) => course.id === courseId);
        
        if(courseIndex > -1){
          
          newCourses[courseIndex] = {
            ...newCourses[courseIndex],
            ...changes,
          };
          console.log(newCourses);
          this.subject.next(newCourses);
        }
      })
```

Otherwise

```ts
private _newCources$ = new BehaviorSubject<Course[]>([]);
newCources$ = this._newCources$.asObservable();
```